# cx_Oracle Inserting Hex ASCII Representation For <bytes> Type Objects Python 3

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

**Behavior:** Inserting a `<bytes>` type object as part of a bound query into an Oracle database column with type `VARCHAR2` inserts the *hex* version of `ord('<char>')` for each character in the string instead of inserting each character itself. See below for an example.

**Version Information:**

- cx-Oracle 7.2.0
- Python 3.6

**Example:**

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.Connection(username, 
                            password,
                            tnsname,
                            threaded=True,
                            encoding='latin1',
                            nencoding='latin1')
cursor = conn.cursor()
row = {'problem_row': b'123'}
cursor.execute('INSERTO INTO table (problem_row) VALUES (:problem_row)', row)
conn.commit()
```

The data is then inserted into the table as `'3132331'`, which if you take a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), are the *hex* versions of `ord('1')`, `ord('2')` and so on for each character.

Changing the encoding on the connection does not appear to have any effect. I would think that this is not the expected functionality, as doing this:

```
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor2.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE problem_row IS NOT NULL')
res = cursor2.fetchall()
```

Results in a `<str>` type with value `'3132331'`.

Is this the intended behavior? Is there any way to change it so that it actually just inserts `123` into the database, and issuing a "SELECT" statement with the cursor returns the correct value?

**Potential Solutions**

- Convert values to `<str>` before inserting them. Seems like there should be a better way to do this, but this is a valid solution that requires more tracking on my end.
- Use something like `binascii.unhexlify` to do the conversion, and then encode them back to `<bytes>` myself. Again, there seems like there should be a more intuitive solution in the cx_Oracle library.
- Looking at the C interfaces that are implemented for the cx-Oracle library, if the Python object `PyBytes_Check(obj)` holds, then it returns a `char*` from `PyBytes_AS_STRING`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a pointer to these literal bytes interpreted as a C `<char>` should still be the correct ASCII string. So maybe this is something wrong on the Oracle side?

Comment: VARCHAR2 is not a binary type.  As well as data conversion in the Oracle layers below cx_Oracle when inserting, you will also get character set conversion between the "client" and database character sets.  Use RAW or BLOB as first choice for the column type.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x, `bytes` objects are bound as `RAW` values in Oracle. This is indeed intended. If you know that those bytes are an encoded string and you wish to store that string in the Oracle database, you will first need to decode it. The only other solution is to use `cursor.setinputsizes()` or create a variable by calling `cursor.var()` telling cx_Oracle that the value is indeed intended as a string. At that point, the bytes will be assumed to be in the correct encoding and should insert as you expect. I'd recommend decoding to string, however, to avoid any potential issues.